# Convert Total Sum Into Percentage

Tags: mysql, percentage

I want to convert a sum result into percentage. When added it will result 100% in total. I already group it by remarks and already got the total from my query. But its still in number.

This is my query

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN A.district = B.district THEN 'Delivered from store in same district'
        WHEN A.city = B.city THEN 'Delivered from store in same city'
        WHEN A.province = B.province THEN 'Delivered from store in same province'
        ELSE 'Not delivered from nearest store'
    END AS 'REMARK',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN YEAR(T1.create_time) = '2019' AND MONTH(T1.create_time) = '01' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Jan-19',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN YEAR(T1.create_time) = '2019' AND MONTH(T1.create_time) = '02' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Feb-19',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN YEAR(T1.create_time) = '2019' AND MONTH(T1.create_time) = '03' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Mar-19', 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN YEAR(T1.create_time) = '2019' AND MONTH(T1.create_time) = '04' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Apr-19'
FROM 
    au_store_add A
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        A.id,
        A.code,
        A.create_time,
        A.plat_create_time,
        A.appoint_stcode,
        A.status
        FROM deli_order A
        WHERE A.appoint_stcode IS NOT NULL
    UNION
        SELECT
        B.id,
        B.code,
        B.create_time,
        B.plat_create_time,
        B.destination_code,
        B.status
        FROM deli_order B
        WHERE B.destination_code IS NOT NULL) T1 ON T1.appoint_stcode = A.store_code
INNER JOIN
    deli_order_delivery B ON B.order_id = T1.id
WHERE 
    YEAR(T1.plat_create_time)='2019' and T1.status = 6 and (month(T1.plat_create_time) in (1,2,3,4))
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN A.district = B.district THEN 'Delivered from store in same district'
        WHEN A.city = B.city THEN 'Delivered from store in same city'
        WHEN A.province = B.province THEN 'Delivered from store in same province'
        ELSE 'Not delivered from nearest store'
    END
```

And the result is like this

```
REMARK                                | Jan-19| Feb-19| Mar-19| Apr-19|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Delivered from store in same city        252      198    308      283
Delivered from store in same district    114      110    163      138 
Delivered from store in same province    1135     976    1387    1208
Not delivered from nearest store         3046     2518   3189    3123
```

I need to generate something like this for each month(without the 'Grand Total')

```
REMARK                                | Jan-19| 
-----------------------------------------------
Delivered from store in same city        5.5%     
Delivered from store in same district    2.5%     
Delivered from store in same province    25%     
Not delivered from nearest store         67%    
Grand Total                              4547  (100%)
```

What should i add to my query?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using MySQL 8.0.13

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using MySQL 8+, then `COUNT()` as an analytic function should be available to use.  It comes in handy here:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN A.district = B.district THEN 'Delivered from store in same district'
        WHEN A.city = B.city THEN 'Delivered from store in same city'
        WHEN A.province = B.province THEN 'Delivered from store in same province'
        ELSE 'Not delivered from nearest store'
    END AS REMARK,
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%Y-%m') = '2019-01' THEN 1 END)
        / COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%Y-%m') = '2019-01'
                     THEN 1 END) OVER () `Jan-19`,
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%Y-%m') = '2019-02' THEN 1 END)
        / COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%Y-%m') = '2019-02'
                     THEN 1 END) OVER () `Feb-19`,
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%Y-%m') = '2019-03' THEN 1 END)
        / COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%Y-%m') = '2019-03'
                     THEN 1 END) OVER () `Mar-19`,
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%Y-%m') = '2019-04' THEN 1 END)
        / COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(create_time, '%Y-%m') = '2019-04'
                     THEN 1 END) OVER () `Apr-19`
FROM 
    au_store_add A
...
```

I used `DATE_FORMAT` above to make the check on the year and month a bit less verbose.  I also used `COUNT` in place of `SUM`, which lets us use a slightly shorter conditional expression.

Comment: I try your query, but it seems the percentage is a bit off. In 'Jan-19' and remark 'Not delivered from nearest store' has 3046 record. It shouldve got more than 50% from the total record for that month.

Comment: Question: Do you want percentages over the _entire_ 2019 year, or do you want to normalize to only January through April?  These are not the same thing, nor the same query.

Comment: 100% for each month

Comment: I want to normalize to only January through April

Comment: I try the query and sum the percentage manually, It seems the percentage total is grouped by remarks, not by the month. Should I change something in my group by query?

Comment: I updated with a solution which should work for MySQL 8+.